# What am I doing wrong with the key implementation in the React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I have the following Code, regarding a React Component:

```
 <FilterGroups
   data={usersList}
   selectedGroups={selectedGroups}
   onChange={this.onFilterSelect}
 />
```

The FilterGroups component is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Icon from 'lenses/common/components/Icon';
import { flatten, uniq, map, pipe } from 'ramda';

import { Dropdown, Toggle, Menu } from 'shared/common/components/LensesDropdown';

class FilterGroups extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array,
    selectedGroups: PropTypes.array,
    onChange: PropTypes.func
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    selectedGroups: []
  };

  renderBadge = () => {
    const { selectedGroups } = this.props;
    if (selectedGroups.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return <span className="badge badge-light ml-1">{selectedGroups.length}</span>;
  };

  onClick = groupName => e => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    e.preventDefault();
    onChange(groupName);
  };

  getAllGroups = data =>
    pipe(
      map(user => user.groups),
      uniq,
      flatten
    )(data);

  render() {
    const { data, selectedGroups } = this.props;

    const allUniqueGroups = this.getAllGroups(data);

    return (
      <Dropdown>
        <Toggle variant="primary">Filter by Group {this.renderBadge()}</Toggle>

        <Menu>
          {allUniqueGroups.map(group => (
            <a
              key={group}
              className="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              href="#"
              onClick={this.onClick(group)}
            >
              <span className="ml-2">{group}</span>
              {selectedGroups.includes(group) && <Icon icon="check" />}
            </a>
          ))}
        </Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}

export default FilterGroups;
```

And I get the following error:`Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`. Also this `Check the render method of`FilterGroups`.`

I am adding a `keyFiled={group}`, inside the component, but I am getting nowhere. I am passing the group as prop as well. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you log the output of `allUniqueGroups`?

Comment: Sadly I can't it will only render after the GroupList is being fetched. It returns `undefined` at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      <a
          key={group}
          className="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
          href="#"
          onClick={this.onClick(group)}
        >
          <span key={group} className="ml-2">{group}</span>
          {selectedGroups.includes(group) && <Icon key={group} icon="check" />}
        </a>
      ))}
```

Insert key into span and Icon.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. I think the problem is more in main screen where the component is used though rather than the key in the Filter Group.. Thanks though..

Answer (score 0):

Just give it an index to be sure they are unique.
allUniqueGroups.map((group, index) and index+group as a key.

Comment: Do you mean something like this. ```<Menu>
          {allUniqueGroups.map((group, index) => (
            <a
              key={index}
              className="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              href="#"
              onClick={this.onClick(group)}
            >
              <span className="ml-2">{group}</span>
              {selectedGroups.includes(group) && <Icon icon="check" />}
            </a>
          ))}
        </Menu>```. I thought of that, the error, seems to go away, but still no data fetched...

Comment: What I get from your comment is do this: `key={index, group},`, which shouldn't work, and it doesn't... Do you mean something else??

Comment: key={group+index} You cant have 2 keys.

Comment: I really don't see how what you just wrote is gonna works. But I will try it. How is group+index is gonna be an elligible key?? Can you explain..

Comment: It will be groupname0, groupname1, groupname2 and so on so if there are 2 same groupnames ita still unique. Actual6 you can do it like key={'groupkey'+index} if there is a posibility of group not being a string

Answer (score 0):

The first thing `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop` is a warning not an error which means that you have another log on your console that shows the error I believe, it could be that `allUniqueGroups` is `undefined` and the solution for this is: Note (`allUniqueGroups &&` at the beginning of the code.

```
{allUniqueGroups && allUniqueGroups.map(group => (
            <a
              key={group}
              className="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              href="#"
              onClick={this.onClick(group)}
            >
              <span className="ml-2">{group}</span>
              {selectedGroups.includes(group) && <Icon icon="check" />}
            </a>
          ))}
```